# Tools to reindex MOV file

Tags: software-recommendation, data-recovery, mov

I have some header corrupted MOV file. Is there are any tools in ubuntu to reindex mov file. I tried to convert the file using ffmpeg but it shows no videos and some audio noise. Also report read stream error.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have no experience doing this but I did find a tool called [foremost](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/oneiric/en/man1/foremost.1.html) that may do it. Can you try it and see if that helps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still it can not be done. Because data are too random. There is no way to find the sequence of data.